# Switch from left click to right click to make character walk in the Top Down Example, in UE4?

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

When creating a new project in the Unreal Engine 4, you can choose to create a project already with some added features and things (**Top Down Example**):

[image]

This project has a character (which I changed its appearance) and it moves around the map when I click the left mouse button:

[image]

I looked at the blueprints of the project, but I did not identify where the command is that makes the character walk, so I'd like it to walk when I right-click.

Alls blueprints of project:

[image]

**M_Cursor_Decal:**

[image]

**TopDownCharacter:**

[image]

**TopDownController:**

[image]

**TopDownGameMode:**

[image]

The circled blocks of reds are the ones I suspected could be where I should make the modification, but no information on them gave me the certainty that that was where I was supposed to change.

I still do not create projects in C ++ programming mode, because I do not have Visual Studio 2017.

Some links from websites where I spent before coming here and that can help you to help me:

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Blueprints

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFXMW_UEDco

***The video is 2015, so although it's good, I did not take it so well, because I know that with all this time that has already happened, a lot is different.***

Sorry for any translation errors, I'm not English speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Edit => ProjectSettings => Engine => Input => Action Mappings:

[image]

1 = Project settings

2 = Input

3 = Action Mappings

4 = Right mouse button (That's where the modification is made)

Link that helped me:

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Gameplay/Input

Comment: My program is in a language other than English, I already looked for the equivalent place to InputTab, without success, could you take a screenshot?

Comment: Look at edit answer

Comment: A simple question, if by chance I create a menu of options or pause, I will command it with the left button of the mouse normally, ok? What I did with what you just answered me modified the button that I make the character move, correct? And do not simply make the right mouse button the default program for all actions.

Comment: No, these are bindings.

Comment: Think about that as a function bound to input key, if you change a key bound to function it only changed for this function. - Also these are not system functions, you can call the functions whatever you want, they will not interfere with widget input.